# I want merge the entire row after that next row display the result

Tags: vb.net

The actual output is:

```
|ctrcode|ctrname|empcode|empname|ewt |percent%|
|_______|_______|_______|_______|____|________|
|1      |Chain  |1001   |A      |25.6|15      |
|_______|_______|_______|_______|____|________|
|2      |Chain  |1002   |B      |15.6|10      |
|_______|_______|_______|_______|____|________|
```

but I want:

```
|empcode|empname|ewt |percent%|
|_______|_______|____|________|
|Chain                        |
|_____________________________|
|1001   |A      |25.6|15      |
|_______|_______|____|________|
|1002   |B      |15.6|10      |
|_______|_______|____|________|
```

How do I get it to look like this? I have used a `DataGridView` and filled the  grid.

Comment: Please try to put some effort in your question! When you are to ask a new question there's a big `How to Format` box on the right where you'll find some basic formatting, and following the [`formatting help`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link in the box will take you to a page explaining different ways to format your question.

Comment: There is also a few more things we need: **1) Your code**. We don't know what your code looks like, and in most cases for questions like this it is impossible to do anything when we don't know how your code works. **2) A thorough** (but not too long) description of what you want to achieve. **3) Your attempts or your research in trying to solve the problem.** We _often_ (not always) want to see that you have actually tried, or tried to find a way to solve your problem. This is due to that Stack Overflow shouldn't be considered a code-writing service. We help you, don't do the work for you.

Comment: Good things to read for newcomers are: [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) || [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) || [**On-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) || and to take the [**Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView is not able to merge cells, as far as I know. Please see this thread, to find an alternative solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/merging-cells-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Have a nice weekend.